# Watch OS2 and NSURLSession

Tags: https, nsurlsession, watch, watchos-2

I made a home automation controller which embedded a web server inside to let users to control their equipments through web interface and API. I was also making an Apple Watch app since OS1 mainly retrieves user ID and password from iPhone then download a plist from the controller and display the information. I rely on NSURLSession to get the plist through LAN to the controller, however since Watch OS2 NSURLSession only allow https connection that my home automation controller cannot provide. In this case any alternative way to let Apple Watch to get the plist from the controller?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Like iOS 9, watchOS 2 uses App Transport Security to enforce secure connections.

> Starting in iOS 9.0 and OS X v10.11, a new security feature called App Transport Security (ATS) is available to apps and is enabled by default. It improves the privacy and data integrity of connections between an app and web services by enforcing additional security requirements for HTTP-based networking requests. Specifically, with ATS enabled, HTTP connections must use HTTPS (RFC 2818). Attempts to connect using insecure HTTP fail.

Since the web server is under your control, the proper approach would be to enable secure HTTPS connections on your server.

If you can't or won't enable that, you could circumvent the security that iOS/watchOS enforces, by adding the appropriate [`NSAppTransportSecurity`](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33) keys to your (watchKit extension's) Info.plist.

This would allow an insecure connection from the watch to your server.